# find canonical basis of matrix $A$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Please send me right direction, I am not sure where I should start.

I have matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}4&1&-3\\0&1&0\\6&1&-5 \end{pmatrix}$$

I heard that I have to find eigenvalues first. I will omit it here as obvious, but what should I do next?

Comment: First eigenvalues (1,1,-2) then eigenvectors.

Comment: @Widawensen Whoops.

Answer (score 1):

After you find the eigenvalues, you need to find the basis vectors for $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$.

In some cases, that produces enough vectors to form a basis. The problem is when a eigenvalue has a multiplicity of $m>1$, but $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ has a dimension $d<m$. In that case, you must look for the basis vectors of $\ker((A-\lambda I)^k)$ for $k=2$, and if then $k=3$ and so on untill you find enough (i.e., $m$) vectors.

Comment: Here we have exactly such case where $d<m$.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical basis of a matrix is a set of linearly independent eigenvectors. Since the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, the rank of this matrix is $3$. Thus our canonical basis must contain $3$ eigenvectors.

Assuming you found the eigenvalues of $A$, you would then need to solve for the corresponding eigenvectors.

In this case, you will get two eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, so one of your eigenvalues will be repeated. For this eigenvalue, say $\lambda_2$, the null space of the map $A - \lambda_2 I$ will have dimension $2$. Find a basis for this eigenspace to find two of the three independent eigenvectors you need.

The last vector in your canonical basis will be the eigenvector which spans the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_1$, i.e. null$(A - \lambda_1 I)$. It is automatically independent from the other two eigenvectors since it corresponds to a different eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to compute bases of the eigenspaces of 
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
4 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
6 & 1 & -5
\end{array}\right]
$$
To do so, start by computing the eigenvalues of $A$ by factoring the characteristic polynomial of $A$
$$
\chi_A(t)=\det(tI-A)=\det\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
t - 4 & -1 & 3 \\
0 & t - 1 & 0 \\
-6 & -1 & t + 5
\end{array}\right]
=t^{3} - 3\,t + 2
=(t + 2) \cdot (t - 1)^{2}
$$
This factorization tells us that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\{-2,1\}$. The algebraic multiplicities of these eigenvalues are $\DeclareMathOperator{am}{am}\am_A(-2)=1$ and $\am_A(1)=2$.

Now, the eigenspace of each eigenvalue of $\lambda$ is defined as $E_\lambda=\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null(\lambda I-A)$.

For $\lambda=-2$, we have
$$
E_{-2}
=\Null(-2\,I-A)
=\Null\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-6 & -1 & 3 \\
0 & -3 & 0 \\
-6 & -1 & 3
\end{array}\right]
=\Null
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
where the last equality is obtained by row-reducing. This implies that $\vec x\in E_{-2}$ if and only if 
$$
\vec x
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
\frac{1}{2}\,x_{3} \\
0 \\
x_{3}
\end{array}\right]
=
x_3
\left[\begin{array}{r}
\frac{1}{2} \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence
$$
E_{-2}=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\left\{\left[\begin{array}{r}
\frac{1}{2} \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]\right\}
$$
That is, $E_{-2}$ is the one-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ with basis $\left\{\left\langle \frac{1}{2},0,1\right\rangle\right\}$. In this situation, we say that $\lambda=-2$ has *geometric multiplicity* $\DeclareMathOperator{gm}{gm}\gm_A(-2)=1$ as an eigenvalue of $A$.

Next, for $\lambda=1$, we have
$$
E_1=\Null(1\,I-A)=\Null
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-3 & -1 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-6 & -1 & 6
\end{array}\right]
=
\Null
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
where again the last equality is obtained by row-reducing. This implies that $\vec x\in E_1$ if and only if 
$$
\vec x=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_{3} \\
0 \\
x_{3}
\end{array}\right]
=
x_3\left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence
$$
E_1=\Span\left\{\left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]\right\}
$$
That is, $E_1$ is the one-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ with basis $\left\{\left\langle 1,0,1\right\rangle\right\}$. Here, the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=1$ as an eigenvalue of $A$ is $\gm_A(1)=1$.

Now, note that $\am_A(-2)=\gm_A(-2)$ while $\am_A(1)>\gm_A(1)$. This means that $A$ is not diagonalizable. In fact, the Jordan canonical form of $A$ is 
$$
J=
\left[\begin{array}{r|rr}
-2 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
since the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue counts the number of Jordan blocks corresponding to the eigenvalue. This means that $A=PJP^{-1}$ for some invertible $P$.

The algorithm for computing $P$ in general is somewhat involved. I recommend reading through [Stefan Fridel's notes on Jordan form](http://math.rice.edu/~friedl/math355_fall04/Jordan.pdf) for a nice detailed exposition.

In your case, we may take $P$ as
$$
P=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
The first column of $P$ is our basis of $E_{-2}$. The second two columns are obtained by extending our basis of $E_{1}$ to a basis of $E_{1}^2=\Null\left((I-A)^2\right)$.